# HTTPS certificate valid while it shouldn't be with mono

Tags: ssl, https, mono, debian, ssl-certificate

So I kind of stumbled over this issue by accident. The situation is like that:

On my Linux device this date is set: `Thu Jan  1 00:59:15 UTC 1970`,
openssl check gives me this result:

```
openssl s_client -connect [prefix].azure-devices.net:443 -CApath /etc/ssl/certs
Verify return code: 9 (certificate is not yet valid)
```

which is ok because the certificate is valid from 2000.

It is still possible to communicate over `https` though. I mean there is no certificate validation error as I would expect.

Can someone explain why?

I use `System.Net.Http.HttpClient` with mono 4.2.3 on debian 8.2 within an LXC container